# How to row reduce a matrix with complex entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, gaussian-elimination

I have been doing some practice questions for university, and one of them is regarding row reducing a complex matrix.
From what I can work out, I think (i could very well be wrong) that the first unknown (row 1) should be (1/32)(41i - 82)
And as such, the second unknown should be (-3-2i) - (2 + 2i)((1/32)(41i - 82))

However this looks messy, and is making me think i may have done it wrong.

If someone could please let me know if i am correct or not, and if not, where i went wrong, i would be hugely grateful.

[image]

Thanks heaps in advance
Corey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is to multiply be the conjugate, giving:
$$\frac{-3+14i}{4-5i}$$
$$\frac{-3+14i}{4-5i} = \frac{-3+14i}{4-5i}\cdot \frac{4+5i}{4+5i} = \frac{-82+41i}{41}=-2+i$$
Thus the second element of the second row now reads:
$$(-3-2i)- (2+2i)(-2+i)=3$$

Comment: That was perfect, thankyou!. I had tried multiplying by the complex conjugate, but i had not expanded it out to simplify it. Thanks again, Corey