# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is the $2\times2$- matrix $$A=\pmatrix{-6&13\\-4&2}$$

The answer of this gives imaginary numbers and I am not sure of how to approach it. 
I found the equation which is $\ x^2+4x+40$

Comment: Do you know the quadratic equation? Use that to find the roots of $$ x^2+4x+40 = 0$$

Comment: yes I wrote it, it is x^2+4x+40, but this gives a negative square root of -144.

Comment: Imaginary numbers can be roots. Clear? See: https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/Quadratics/QDcomplex.html

Comment: If you try and find the roots, with the fomula x=b^2-4ac/2a, the squre root in -144 and I don't know how to approach this situation to find the eigenvalues.

Comment: The square root of $-144$ (in the complex numbers) is $\pm 12i$

Comment: Do you know or have you seen an imaginary number is $\sqrt{-1} = i$. These can be roots and/or eigenvalues of a matrix.

Comment: so the two eigen values whould be 4i and -8i

Comment: No, they would be $$-2 ~ \pm ~ 6~i$$

Comment: No, $-2\pm 6i$ is the result. @Moo You were some seconds faster :)

Comment: @Peter: No worries! :-)

Comment: and using that how do you find the eigenvectors

Comment: Now, since these are complex conjugate eigenvalues, you will have complex conjugate eigenvectors - so you really need to only find one. You need to solve $$[A - \lambda_1 I] v_1 = 0$$ Use RREF to figure out the eigenvector $v_1$ and $v_2$ will just be the conjugate. See, for example http://www.math.vt.edu/people/afkhamis/class_home/notes/F08W11b.pdf or https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_7text.pdf

Comment: with real numbers, you just do A-lamda(I) and you plug in the values and do RREF

Comment: how am I supposed to do RREF with the i

Comment: @Moo I am not sure whether the asker is allowed to use RREF: This is a slight shortcut, but in the case of such a small matrix, the gain is not that big. I think , just calculating both eigenvectors is a good exercise.

Comment: @Peter: She mentions it above, but I am not sure what she is allowed to use. If I can infer, it will be useful to learn regardless because I think they'll be required to do $2x2$ and $3x3$ examples.

Comment: @RachelNewborn: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192241/how-to-row-reduce-a-matrix-with-complex-entries or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmHBGIC1_Z0 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Jb2jEjgbI

Comment: @Moo Oh, I overlooked the comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the work to find an eigenvector for each eigenvalue: I am doing $-2+6i$ for you:
$$\pmatrix{-6&13\\-4&2}\pmatrix{x\\y}=(-2+6i)\pmatrix{x\\y}$$
Working out gives the following 2 equations:
$$-6x+13y=-2x+6ix$$
$$-4x+2y=2y+6iy$$
Now there are several ways to proceed. One way is to solve the first equation for $y$: $$13y=(4+6i)x$$
Solve the second equation for $x$ gives:
$$-4x=(-4+6i)y$$
These equations are the same but it certainly doesn't look like it, does it? Take the first equation and multiply left and right by conjugate $(4-6i)$:
You get $13(4-6i)y=52x$ which simplifies to $(4-6i)y=4x$ which is the second equation.(Knock off the minus). So now pick for example $y=2$ to find $x=2-3i$ and we have an eigenvector $\pmatrix{2-3i\\2}$. You try the other one.